# Can't get first level of a structure

Tags: structure

I have a structure with content:

- Item A

  - Item AA
- Item B

  - Item BB

I get nothing when I explicitly call the first level with `.level('1')`:

`{% set entries = craft.entries().section('pages').orderBy('title asc').level('1').all() %}`

But I DO get the second level when I explicitly select it with `.level('2')`:

`{% set entries = craft.entries().section('pages').orderBy('title asc').level('2').all() %}`

Any thoughts on what could be wrong? Trying to just get the first level.

Comment: Are the entries published, not expired, not pending etc?

Answer (score 1):

Welp.... turns out I was using CSS Grid for my rendered items, and since it was a gallery items without images were collapsing the grid.

Problem solved.